# How do I iterate json data and show it in div place holder with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a banner management script. In action page, a jquery post process realized like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'ajax/impressions.php',
  data: {placeholders: bannerPlaceholders.join(',')},
  success: function (response) {
    if(response) {
      for (var placeholderId in response) {
        var x = '<a id="banner-'+response[placeholderId]['banner_id']+'" class="banner-tracker" href="'+response[placeholderId]['href']+'" target="_blank">';   
        x += '<img alt="'+response[placeholderId]['href']+'" src="storage/'+response[placeholderId]['src']+'" />';
        x += '</a>';
        $('#banner-placeholder-'+placeholderId).html(x);                        
       }
     }
   }
});
```

and data arrives like this:
 `{"1":{"banner_id":"1","src":"banner125x125.gif","href":"http://stackoverflow.com"}}`

And the last a html placeholder like this : `<div id="banner-placeholder-1" class="banner-placeholder" style="width:125px;height:125px;border:1px solid grey;"></div>`

My problem: banner is not shown in place holder. I did not manage what I do. Could you help me, how do I show the banner in the placeholder?
Kind regards.

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving data as an array in the `success` function? Because what you show is not an array.

Comment: In impression.php code like this: `echo json_encode($banners);`

Comment: I think you're confusing javascript with PHP a bit here... You have to make sure your response is in the array format: `[{"banner_id":1, "src": "...", "href":"..."}, {...}, ...]`. If it's not, your code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set the html of nonexistent divs. At the end of the `each` block, you set `$('#banner-placeholder-{id}').html` -- .html will set the inner html of that div. However, you won't see this, because there is probably no `#banner-placeholder-3` in your dom.

Try, instead, to append to an existing element in your page. For example, you could do:

```
$('body').append(x)
```

Comment: Yes, in my page there is no div named `#banner-placeholder-3`. But I did not understand `$('body').append(x)`. Sorry, my beginners level.

Comment: You are trying to add the results to your page, correct? That HTML you are generating in to `x` needs to be added to the page. Calling .html on a nonexistant div will put that nowhere, since jquery won't find the div. Instead you need to `append` -- which *adds* the html to the page. If, for instance, you have a container called #banners-container that you wished to add the results to, you would do `$('#banners-container').append(x)`. This will add `x` to the end of #banners-container.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of `banner-placeholder`class, try to remove it:

```
$('#banner-placeholder-'+placeholderId).html(x).removeClass('banner-placeholder');
```

If it doesn't work please comment.

Comment: It did not work. Because when I add `alert(response[placeholderId]['src']` in for loop, it returns `undefined`. I think there is a problem in for loop.